# list comprehension for list of list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I have a list of lists and I want to find the indices where '//' occurs. I know how to do it if I use nested loops but, I want to use list comprehension. My list is:

```
ex = [['foo', 'faa'], ['//', 'sd'], ['foo', 'kaa'], ['side', 'haha', 'blue'], ['//', 'sd']]
```

How can I use list comprehension here to find indices where '//' occurs? What I've done so far is:

```
indices = [idx for idx, lst in enumerate(ex)]
```

This gives me the indices of my lists in the list. But I don't know how to use these to find indices for `'//'` using list comprehension.

For the above `ex` example, the expected output is

```
[1, 4]
```

e.g. the indices for the nested lists containing `'//'`, which are `ex[1]` and `ex[4]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This comprehension will do:

```
>>> indices = [idx for idx, lst in enumerate(ex) if "//" in lst]
>>> indices
[1, 4]
```

If you want to check if "//" is present inside any strings in the lists:

```
>>> indices = [idx for idx, lst in enumerate(ex) if any("//" in x for x in lst)]
```

Comment: @ShafaHaider, your question was eddited, but i was checking if "//" was present in any string within the lists

Answer (score 8):

Nested list comprehensions are only needed when the *output* contains nested lists. List comprehensions produce lists, nested list comprehensions produce a list of lists. You are only producing indices here, for each nested list that passes a test.

If all you want to do is test for the `'//'` string being in the nested list, just use a filtering `if` expression in the list comprehension:

```
indices = [idx for idx, lst in enumerate(ex) if '//' in lst]
```

If you need to know if `'//'` is a *substring* of any of the values, then it's still a filter test, but with the [`any()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) and a generator expression:

```
indices = [idx for idx, lst in enumerate(ex) if any('//' in el for el in lst)]
```

The `any()` function iterates over the generator expression one step at a time, and the moment a result produced is a true value, it'll stop iterating and return `True`. This makes for a very efficient method of testing your nested lists.